# using Selenium 2 / Web Driver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-ide, selenium-webdriver

I have recently been looking at using Selenium 2 / webdriver for some automated web tests.  The API looks great.  However is it possible to record a test through the selenium-IDE and generate C# code for webdriver.  I have found some Java formatters, but can't find anyway to do this for C#.

Whilst the IDE's Export Test Case As/C# works, the code it generates is for the previous Selenium 1/RC not the new Selenium2/WebDriver API.

Answer (score 3):

In the newer versions of Selenium IDE this option now exists under File > Export Test Case As...

The option is called **C# (NUnit) - WebDriver Backed**.

[image: Export Test Case As... submenu]

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable using the API i would suggest leaving the IDE behind you. Whatever generator you will find, at some point it will generate an unmanageable mess. I would suggest to take a look at the selenium design pattern at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesignPatterns . For instance the pagefactory makes it pretty easy to quickly make pages accesible through properties and you will be doing so in a maintainable manner.

testcode is far more easy to refactor into maintainable code, whereas this is far more difficult for recorded testcases in selenium IDE

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but Selenium IDE 1.0.10 under Options / Format has an entry for C# which will convert the IDE test to C# format.

Comment: Yes indeed but for the Selenium 1.0 API.  There is nothing I can find which will generate the equivalent for the Selenium 2 / Webdriver API.

Answer (score -2):

1.There is a plugin that can convert selinium 1 scripts to webdrive java. Unfortuantely it is claimed that the current implementation of C# is incomplete. I think I will just use Java instead.